# Having problems going from mysqli_query to mysqli_prepare

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to PHP and made a simple php site that allows me to submit a form and delete data stored in a database. I was told it was better to use prepared statements to avoid SQL Injection.

I updated my delete and it still works, not sure if it's totally right:

```
<?php

include("dbconnect.php");

$getid = $_GET["id"];
$delete = mysqli_prepare($database,"DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id IN ($getid)");
mysqli_stmt_execute($delete);

header("Location:http://localhost/address-book");
exit;

?>
```

But I can't seem to get the add to database feature to work. I tried a variety of different ways to write it, but I'm sure that I'm missing something simple. Here's the unsafe code that I originally wrote:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

include("inc/dbconnect.php");

// assigns form data to table columns
$assign = "INSERT INTO contacts(firstName,lastName,email,phone,birthday) VALUES ('$_POST[firstName]','$_POST[lastName]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[birthday]')";

//execute query
if (mysqli_query($database,$assign)) {
    header("Location:http://localhost/address-book/");
    exit;
} else {
    exit;
}

?>
```

If someone could guide me in the right direction I'd be thankful. I'm new to all of this.

**UPDATED: I've updated my original code and came up with this instead for delete:**

```
<?php

include("dbconnect.php");

$getid = $_GET["id"];
$delete = mysqli_prepare($database,"DELETE FROM contacts WHERE id IN (?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($delete, 's', $getid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($delete);

header("Location:http://localhost/address-book");
exit;

?>
```

**and the add feature:**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

include("inc/dbconnect.php");

$firstName = "$_POST[firstName]";
$lastName = "$_POST[lastName]";
$email = "$_POST[email]";
$phone = "$_POST[phone]";

// assigns form data to table columns
$assign = mysqli_prepare($database,"INSERT INTO contacts(firstName,lastName,email,phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($assign, 'ssss', $firstName, $lastName, $email, $phone);
mysqli_stmt_execute($assign);
exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use placeholders [(?)](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Prepare statement is something along the lines of

`$query = $this->db->prepare("Query here WHERE something = ?")` - note this example is taken from my site so you'll likely have something else instead of `$this->->prepare.`

The key thing is that the `"= something "` is denoted as a question mark.

You then bind the value of that question mark to the query

```
$query->bindValue(1, passed in parameter)
```

As a fully working example:

```
    //function to add 1 to downloads each time a file is downloaded
public function addToDownload($filename){

    $query = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE trainingMaterial SET downloads = downloads + 1 WHERE filename = ?');
    $query->bindValue(1, $filename);

    try{

        $query->execute();

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}


Your query `$assign = "INSERT INTO contacts(firstName,lastName,email,phone,birthday) VALUES ('$_POST[firstName]','$_POST[lastName]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[birthday]')";
```

would be

```
$assign = "INSERT INTO contacts(firstName,lastName,email,phone,birthday) VALUES ?,?,?,?,?)";
$assign->bindValue(1, '$_POST[firstName]')
$assign->bindValue(2, '$_POST[lastName]')
```

etc etc

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty easy to understand.

Comment: NO problem, I had a couple of issues myself but once you have an example it;s dead simple.  I wouldn't use anything else now. :)

Comment: I've updated my code based on your suggestions and edited it into my original question. It works, hopefully it's more secure than before.

Comment: That's great news! :)